# Can't auto create jsconfig.json in Visual studio as green bulb is missing

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to create a jsconfig.json file, but Visual studio is not showing me the green bulb that allows me to do this. I'm used to finding the green bulb at the bottom right of the editor like this image is showing.

[image: like this,but i do not have]

Why can't I see the green bulb?

Answer (score 2):

> ### Writing jsconfig.json
>
> When VS Code **detects** that you are **working
>   on a JavaScript file**, it looks to see if you have a JavaScript
>   configuration file jsconfig.json in your workspace. If it doesn't find
>   one, you will see a green lightbulb on the Status Bar prompting you to
>   create one. Click the green lightbulb and accept the prompt to create
>   a jsconfig.json file.
>   ([source](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_location-of-jsconfigjson))

It looks like the availability of the green lightbulb is determined by the currently opened file being a javascript file.

Otherwise just create a `jsconfig.json` file yourself:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript now infers the JavaScript project if no `jsconfig.json` is found. This means that the green light bulb hint about creating a `jsconfig.json` file is not required so it was removed from vscode in November iteration (1.7.0 or 1.7.1). The vscode documentation was not yet updated to reflect that change.

Related PR: [vscode/pull/15213](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/15213)
Related plan item: [vscode/issues/15205](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15205)

**tl;dr** Starting from vscode 1.7.1 you don't need the `jsconfig.json` file unless you are overwriting/extending default setting.

Comment: This is correct. I've now updated the documentation to remove references to the light bulb. You still need a `jsconfig.json` to get rich intellisense for some Javascript project types but we will not show this alert automatically anymore. Let me know if the documentation is still unclear or could be improved: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues Thanks